# Display two different array return value in single table in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

> I want to show return two array value in a single table in view,i already run first array value in table.
>
> controller

```
public function communication(){
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');
    $id = $session_data['id'];     
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')) {
        $data['get_all_mail'] = $this->admin_model->get_all_mails($id);
        $data['get_out_mail'] = $this->admin_model->get_out_mails($id);           
        $this->load->view('communication',$data);
    }
}
```

> model

```
function get_all_mails($id){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM t_communication_posting WHERE FIND_IN_SET($id, REPLACE(`to`, ', ', ',')) OR FIND_IN_SET($id, REPLACE(`cc`, ', ', ',')) OR FIND_IN_SET($id, REPLACE(`bcc`, ', ', ',')) <> 0");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

> view

```
                          <table id="myTable">
                            <tbody>
                                <?php foreach ($get_all_mail as 
                                  $get_all_mails) { ?>
                                    <tr onclick="return get_mail_content(<?
                    php echo $get_all_mails['m_id']; ?>)" id="target-list">                                     
                                        </td>                                                                     
                                <td class="email-title" >
                                    <?php echo $get_all_mails['from']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td class="email-body" >
                                    <?php echo $get_all_mails['subject'] ?>
                                </td>                                                                       
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

> Here i want to run second array value ($data['get_out_mail']) in above table on view page,how i run two array value in single table.

Comment: you can run the second foreach after completion of first foreach

Answer (score 0):

you can run the `second foreach` after completion of `first foreach` like below

```
<table id="myTable">
      <tbody>
           <?php foreach ($get_all_mail as $get_all_mails) { ?>

                    //...... tr here 

           <?php } ?>

          <?php foreach ($get_out_mail as $get_out_mails) { ?>

                 //...... tr here

          <?php } ?>

      </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another loop in your view file.

```
<?php foreach ($get_all_mail as $get_all_mails) {
    ?>
    <tr onclick="return get_mail_content(<?php echo $get_all_mails['m_id']; ?>)" id="target-list">                                     
        <td class="email-title" >
            <?php echo $get_all_mails['from']; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="email-body" >
            <?php echo $get_all_mails['subject'] ?>
        </td>                                                                       
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

<?php foreach ($get_out_mail as $get_out_mails) {
    ?>
    <tr onclick="return get_mail_content(<?php echo $get_out_mails['m_id']; ?>)" id="target-list">                                     
        <td class="email-title" >
            <?php echo $get_out_mails['from']; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="email-body" >
            <?php echo $get_out_mails['subject'] ?>
        </td>                                                                       
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

This will help you.

Comment: i cant get ,here you use onclick event ,can you explain why you use on click

Comment: I just copied loop from your question. You should better know why you have used this.